# How to clean Liferay files and server diskspace

Tags: java, liferay

I am working on Liferay system, where I uploaded almost 400 GB data.
Because of some unavoidable reason, I deleted all the files from Liferay.
But when I check at disk, I can still see disk is occupying almost same data what I uploaded.

As I cant delete the files from document library, Can anybody please suggest how to clean my disk?
I want to upload that data again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Temporary folders/files that can be removed:

- /LIFERAY/data/lucene
- /LIFERAY/data/jackrabbit
- /LIFERAY/data/osgi
- /LIFERAY/logs/ (all files)
- /LIFERAY/TOMCAT/temp
- /LIFERAY/TOMCAT/work
- /LIFERAY/TOMCAT/logs/ (all files)

Comment: Don't take this without checking: The "jackrabbit" directory should only be deleted if you don't use it for your document library (otherwise you loose all your data stored there). Deleting the "lucene" directory requires you to reindex the search index, potentially creating  equally-sized files afterwards (and using up a lot of time). And deleting the osgi folder probably will not free up too much space, I'd rather leave it complete. And the tomcat/work folder will cause the portal to be extremely slow after the next start on first display of each page.

Answer (score 3):

Which server are you using? It is different for **tomcat** and **jboss**.

### How to clean Tomcat?

1. Delete all files inside ***$LIFERAY_HOME_DIRECTORY/tomcat-7.0.40/work
   /webapps*** except **ROOT**
2. Delete all files inside ***$LIFERAY_HOME_DIRECTORY/tomcat-7.0.40/logs***
3. Delete all files inside ***$LIFERAY_HOME_DIRECTORY/tomcat-7.0.40/tomcat-7.0.40/work***
4. Do the fresh deployment and restart the server.

### How to clean Jboss?

1. Delete all files inside ***$LIFERAY_HOME_DIRECTORY/logs***
2. Delete all files inside ***$LIFERAY_HOME_DIRECTORY/jboss-eap-6.1/standalone/tmp***
3. Clean directory ***$LIFERAY_HOME_DIRECTORY/jboss-eap-6.1/standalone/log***
4. Stop the server and clean directory ***$LIFERAY_HOME_DIRECTORY/jboss-eap-6.1/standalone/deployments*** except **ROOT.war** and **ROOT.war.dodeploy**
5. Do the fresh deployment and restart the server.

### How to clean document directory?

1. Clean ***$LIFERAY_HOME_DIRECTORY/data/***

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Sanjaya.. Will check by deleting the doc directory.

Comment: if you delete $liferay.home/data, you will loose all your data that is stored in the document library (unless you've configured it to be somewhere else). If that's what you want: Go ahead. If you have data there that you need: Keep a backup ready. Hopefully you've thought of backing up the document library.